# Gain of a signal passed through a N element phased array?

Tags: antenna, gain, dsp, antenna-array

Assuming a isotropic phased array of N elements, the gain would be 10*log10(N) dB which is provided in theory.
However, when same signal is passed through all the N elements, the gain is 20 * log10(N) when simulated.

This seems to make sense as the signal is same, and thus strongly correlated. Even statistically, it seems to indicate that assuming 2 Random variable that are added by a 2 element array and power is calculated.

Like E{ (X + Y) ^2 } = E{X^2} + E {Y^2 } + 2 E {XY}

If X and Y are uncorrelated then E {XY } = 0. But if X = Y

E{ (X + Y) ^2 } = 4 * E{X^2} or 4 * pow(X)

This gives a total gain of 6.02 dB for 2 elements (as opposed to 3.01 dB). I see 3.01 dB of gain only when signals are uncorrelated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you considering absolute signal gain? Or a gain in signal-to-noise (SNR) ratio?

Comment: Are you maybe mixing up voltage gain vs power gain?